# ObjectCache does not contain item immediently after setting it consistently

Tags: c#, objectcache

All-
I am attempting to create a server-side cache using the new ObjectCache object. For whatever reason, the following is throwing an exception...

```
_cache.Set(CacheKey.LOCATIONS, cachedLocations, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(2));
                    if (!_cache.Contains(CacheKey.LOCATIONS))
                        throw new Exception("Did not add location to the cache.");
```

_cache is instantiated in the following way on the service layer...

```
private ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

This exception occures every time the cache is being set, except the first time. The exception is the one shown in the code... "Did not add location to the cache."

---Edit note. ObjectCache was static, but there is no need for it to be static since MemoryCache.Default is static.

Comment: is it possible the set is being done on another thread? What if you do a wait and check again?

Comment: There is a lock (this){...} around the code above, so I do not believe it would be possible.

Comment: That isn't going to help anything. Maybe if you use lock(_cache){}. Did you test this theory by waiting before trying?

Comment: DustinDavis, I appreciate your help however  I do not believe I catch your meaning. What do you mean wait and check again? 

Also, lock(this) appears to be working fine. I ran a unit test that span up multiple threads that called my "AddLocationToCache" method and they all ran sequentially. Also I log each exception and when "AddLocationToCache" is called multiple times, the timestamp on each log indicates a sequential execution.

Comment: is CacheKey.LOCATIONS a string?

Comment: Yes. "Locations" is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Add() method to create a new entry in the cache.
The Set() method involves the key already exists.